# How to set a default datatable height size in rows?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I want to set the  height to a default size in rows. Is that possible? 
I want that, even if there are no data in table, it will have a default size.
This is my code:

```
<p:dataTable id="models" var="model" 
                     value="#{myManagedBean.lazyModel}"
                     rowKey="#{model.id}"
                     selection="#{myManagedBean.selectedRow}"
                     selectionMode="single"
                     paginator="true"                                          
                     rows="20"
                     currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} of {totalPages} page(s) - {totalRecords} row(s)"                                          
                     paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"
                     lazy="true"
                     paginatorPosition="bottom"
                     style="white-space:nowrap!important; height:150px">
```

I Tried to put the "height:150px" in style but it didn't work.

Comment: Did you check the primefaces showcase?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the primefaces [datatable scroll showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml):

```
<p:dataTable var="car" value="#{dtScrollView.cars1}" scrollable="true" scrollHeight="150">
```

Comment: You are welcome... Hope you check the PF showcase and documentation next time before asking, or just scan it from time to time... Might save you and us some time (scanning PF posts  here and in the PF forum helps to to gain knowledge